# Dialogflow fulfillment parameter not accessible

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm currency trying out dialogflow fulfillment with NodeJS (dialogflow-fulfillment).

I am trying to access the parameters from dialogflow, but when I'm trying to access the `currency-name` parameter I get the following error: `ReferenceError: name is not defined`

But when I print the parameters I get: `parameters: {"currency-name":["GBP","USD"],"number":500}`

Currently using this code:

```
agent.add("parameters: " + JSON.stringify(agent.parameters.currency-name));
agent.add("parameters: " + JSON.stringify(agent.parameters));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `agent.parameters.currency-name` is treated as trying to access `agent.parameters.currency` and subtracting what is in `name`.

To reference a parameter name that includes characters besides letters and numbers, you need to use `[]` referencing and a string for the name. Something like this:

```
agent.parameters['currency-name']
```

You can also change the name of the parameter in Dialogflow to remove the hyphen.